# What is the purpose of the parameters in the data section

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there some documentation that explains the parameters in the data section? I don't know create parameter in data label. Example, I have 2 signal

```
x1 = 100*cos(2*pi*200*t); 
x2 = 500*cos(2*pi*500*t);
x = x1 + x2;
```

How should I write it? (Block in serial for MATLAB Simulink)

[image: Block parameters]

Answer (score 0):

The steps are quite simple, in Matlab command window define your time vector and the signal:

```
t = 0:0.01:10; % define time
x1 = 100*cos(2*pi*200*t'); % create signal
x1_in = [t',x1]; % create variable containing both time and signal
```

then in Simulink, in the FromWorkspace block Parameters value just write reference the name of the signal:

[image]

Repeat the same for the second signal.
Then sum them using sum block to get `x=x1+x2`

[image]

Comment: not implement to scope when add two 2 signal. Hjx

Comment: sorry but i dont understand the question